# Facing using while doing token classification using BLOOM LLM Model

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to import BloomTokenizer:

```py
from transformers import BloomTokenizer, BloomModel
```

but receive the following error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-7a6e1f78a498> in <module>()
----> 1 from transformers import BloomTokenizer, BloomForTokenClassification
      2 import torch

ImportError: cannot import name 'BloomTokenizer' from 'transformers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/__init__.py)
```

PS: Transformer version 4.2

Comment: Bloom was added with transformers 4.20.0. Please upgrade your package.

Comment: I have the proper version of the package, however it still throws an error. I came across a similar issue with a different model and it turned out that one another package was missing. Perhaps here is the same?

Comment: @Marcel The OP wrote that he is using 4.2. He should at first upgrade his package and report back if it is still not working as expected.

Answer (score -2):

There is no BloomTokenizer but you can use BloomTokenizerFast

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).